# Save a received picture to a folder on a web server

Tags: java, android, spring, spring-mvc, webserver

I am to send a picture from an android phone to a local web server on my computer. I'd like to save the picture to a folder on the local server. My plan is to write some kind of controller that takes care of the received picture and saves it. So basically I think I need to create a controller that takes in a parameter (the picture) and saves it to a folder at the server. I have been searching all over and haven't yet found what I'm looking for.

Therefore what I'd like to know is: 
How is such a controller written.

I am currently using Apache Tomcat/7.0.39 web server, Spring MVC Framework through STS and my OS is Windows 7.

Aprreciate any help I can get! 
 Code examples would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you, 
Mat

Comment: I suppose the picture is preferably sent as a Base64 String. I have heard something about Post requests, might that be helpful?

Comment: In general, what you are looking for is a "file upload handler". Try searching on that, there are many easier options for doing this if you don't have to use Spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) is pretty easy to use to process multipart form posts.  I don't think I've used it with Spring MVC, but there are [examples](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/) out there.

Comment: Yes I just discovered it and managed to wright a controller that does the job.

Comment: Also do you know if there is a good way to send a picture from Android phone to a server that uses the commons fileupload?`(Basically how to write the code)

Comment: Do you mean from a web form on the Android browser, or direct from the file system?  If it's an html form, you just specify enctype="mulipart/form-data" in the form tag and provide an input with type="file".  If it's from the file system, you wouldn't need the FileUpload library in the servlet.  You could send the data in an http post (check out java.net.HttpURLConnection).  Then in the servlet, you just read the binary ServletInputStream and buffer the data into a FileOutputStream.

Comment: Yes it's a HTML form on the server side. It looks something like this: `<html>
    <head>
        <title>Upload a file please</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
        <form method="post" action="/form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="name"/>
            <input type="file" name="file"/>
            <input type="submit"/>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>`

Comment: The code on the android side is to long to post here but these are the (at least I think) most important lines: String url = "http://localhost:8080/springmvc/upload";  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "fileDir");  HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);   InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(file), -1);   reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");  reqEntity.setChunked(true);  httppost.setEntity(reqEntity); HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

Answer (score 0):

For a similar function (loading photos from Android to servlet), here's the Android client code I use (edited slightly for posting here):

```
URI uri = URI.create(// path to file);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.STRICT);
// several key-value pairs to describe the data, one should be filename
entity.addPart("key", new StringBody("value"));

File inputFile = new File(photoUri.getPath());
// optionally reduces the size of the photo (you can replace with FileInputStream)
InputStream photoInput = getSizedPhotoInputStream(photoUri);
entity.addPart("CONTENT", new InputStreamBody(photoInput, inputFile.getName()));

HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(uri); 
HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();

httppost.setEntity(entity);     
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost, localContext);
```

and here's the code to receive it. First, be sure to tag your servlet class as supporting multipart messages:

```
@MultipartConfig
public class PhotosServlet extends HttpServlet
```

and then the relevant part of the body:

```
HttpEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(request.getPart("CONTENT").getInputStream(), contentLength);
InputStream inputFile = entity.getContent();

// string extension comes from one of the key-value pairs
String extension = request.getParameter(//filename key);

// first write file to a file
File images = new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("images"));
File filePath = File.createTempFile("user", extension, images);
writeInputDataToOutputFile(inputFile, filePath); // just copy input stream to output stream
String path = filePath.getPath();

logger.debug("Wrote new file, filename: " + path);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, I went for a similar solution!

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I went with using STS with MVC Framework template:

The controller:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {@RequestMapping(value = "/upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String handleFormUpload(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) throws IOException {
if (!file.isEmpty()) {
    byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(
            "C:\\Users\\Mat\\Desktop\\image.bmp");
    try {
        fos.write(bytes);
    } finally {
        fos.close();
    }
    return "works";
} else {
    return "doesn't work";
}
}

}
```

The .jsp file (the form):

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Upload a file please</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please upload a file</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         <input type="file" name="file"/>
        <input type="submit"/>  
    </form>
</body>
```