# sending both audio file and values from android to server

Tags: java, android

i know for uploading audio in android, i can do like this :

```
final byte[] data = out.toByteArray();
String urlString = "http://localhost/voiceupload.php";
HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(urlString);
postRequest.setEntity(new  ByteArrayEntity(data)); //data is a byte array containing sound in the form of bytearray
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
```

for uploading simple values i can do like this :

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("callid", "8123069127952"));
UrlEncodedFormEntity formEntity = null;
try {
formEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters);
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
  e1.printStackTrace();
 }
httpPost.setEntity(formEntity);
client.execute(postRequest)
```

Now i want to send both in one post request.I mean i want to send one or more variable values and one sound file.Can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. See my answer at this post:
[Save a received picture to a folder on a web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16596664/save-a-received-picture-to-a-folder-on-a-web-server/16620432#16620432)
Just replace the image file with the sound file.
Where it passes just one value, the filename, you can add as many name-value pairs as you'd like.

Comment: MultipartEntity class is inside apache or java or android ? i don't think so. or is it ?

Comment: It's an apache library: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/apidocs/org/apache/http/entity/mime/MultipartEntity.html